# QQoutesPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and QQoutesPageModule

Tags: ionic-framework

I have added `QQoutesPage` in Ionic, if I add in `app.modules.ts` at the `@NgModule` list I am getting the Error saying

> QQoutesPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and
>   QQoutesPageModule!*

if I remove the `QQoutesPages` from the `@NgModules` list I am getting --

> Error: Component QQoutesPage is not part of any NgModule or the module
>   has not been imported into your module.

**app/modules.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { FavoritesPage } from '../pages/favorites/favorites';
import { LibraryPage } from '../pages/library/library';
import { QuotePage } from '../pages/quote/quote';
import { SettingsPage } from '../pages/settings/settings';
import { tabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { QQoutesPage } from '../pages/q-qoutes/q-qoutes';
import { QuotesServices } from '../services/quotes';



@NgModule({
declarations: [
  MyApp,
FavoritesPage,
LibraryPage,
QuotePage,
SettingsPage,
tabsPage ,QQoutesPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    FavoritesPage,
    LibraryPage,
    QuotePage,

    SettingsPage,
    tabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    QuotesServices,QQoutesPage
     ]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Remove the page import from anywhere outside QQoutesPageModule

Comment: remove the `QQoutesPage.module.ts` file and also remove `@IonicPage` from your `QQoutesPage.ts` file. hope it will help

Comment: @Suraj Rao Yes, i removed it from NgModule, but Now i got Different error saying Error: 
    "Unexpected directive 'LibraryPage' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a NgModule annotation." ,

Comment: are all your pages lazy loaded?

Comment: No .. i am not using Lazy loading ..